# Insert an element in a list into kth position each sublist (from left to right after inserting k+=1) of another list- Python

Tags: python, for-loop, insert

There are 3 subsets in Spi, each subset contains its sublists  and I denoted it as Spi[d][l] (d is the number of subsets and l is the number of sublists).

I want to enter each subset to insert just one specific number which is an element of S_inter into the 3rd, 4th, and 5th (3, 4, 5 are elements of in_inter_job) position of each sublist respectively.

To be more clear, that is inserting number 4 into the first subset, next is number 2 entering to the second subset (2 will be inserted into position 3 of the first sublist, position 4 in the second sublist and 5th position in the last sublist), the do the same for number 6 and the last subset.

```
S_inter=[4, 2, 6]

in_inter_job=[ 3, 4, 5]
```

```
Spi=[[[1, 3, 5, 2, 6], [1, 3, 5, 2, 6], [1, 3, 5, 2, 6]], [[1, 3, 5, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5, 4, 6]], [[1, 3, 5, 4, 2], [1, 3, 5, 4, 2], [1, 3, 5, 4, 2]]]
```

The result I wanted is like :

```
Spi=[[[1, 3, 5, 4, 2, 6], [1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5, 2, 6, 4]], [[1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5, 4, 2, 6], [1, 3, 5, 4, 6, 2]], [[1, 3, 5, 6, 4, 2], [1, 3, 5, 4, 6, 2], [1, 3, 5, 4, 2, 6]]]
```

But after I run these for loop:

```
for d in range(0,len(Spi)):

    for k in S_inter:
        for l, r in zip(range(len(Spi[d])),in_inter_job):
            Spi[d][l].insert(r,k)
            if len(Spi[d][l]) == 6:
                break
print(" After insert ",Spi)
```

then I get result:

```
Spi=[[[1, 3, 5, 6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 6], [1, 3, 5, 6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 6], [1, 3, 5, 6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 6]], [[1, 3, 5, 6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5, 6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5, 6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 6]], [[1, 3, 5, 6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2], [1, 3, 5, 6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2], [1, 3, 5, 6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2]]]
```

Please help me!

Comment: What is the logic?

Comment: There are 3 subsets in Spi, each subset contains its sublists (in the above example also has 3 sublists) and I denoted it as Spi[d][l] (d is the number of subsets and l is the number of sublists). I want to enter each subset to insert just one specific number which is an element of S_inter into the 3rd, 4th, and 5th (3, 4, 5 are elements of in_inter_job) position of each sublist respectively.

Comment: To be more clear, that is inserting number 4 into the first subset ( 4 will be inserted into position 3 of the first sublist, position 4 in the second sublist and 5th position in the last sublist), next is number 2 entering to the second subset ( 2 will be inserted into position 3 of the first sublist, position 4 in the second sublist and 5th position in the last sublist), the do the same for number 6 and the last subset.

Answer (score 0):

Simple nested for loop to insert into each list in Spi at corresponding position in in_inter_job with corresponding value in S_inter:

```
S_inter=[4, 2, 6]
in_inter_job=[ 3, 4, 5]
Spi=[[[1, 3, 5, 2, 6], [1, 3, 5, 2, 6], [1, 3, 5, 2, 6]], [[1, 3, 5, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5, 4, 6]], [[1, 3, 5, 4, 2], [1, 3, 5, 4, 2], [1, 3, 5, 4, 2]]]
for i, x in enumerate(S_inter):
    for j, L in enumerate(Spi[i]):
        pos = in_inter_job[j]
        L.insert(pos, x)

print(Spi)
```

Your zip (which is similar to what enumerate above is doing) doesn't work, because it doesn't match your logic.  The positions of in_inter_job do not directly correspond with the indexes in S_inter, and so you end up inserting the wrong values, because you're trying to use the same index for both lists.